# How to find duplicate rows in a column then find out if two cells in another column sum up to a third cell in an Excel tab in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I need to find all duplicate rows (string values) in "Name" column and then find out if two numerical values in "Amount" column sum up to a third value also in the "Amount" column in an Excel tab in Pandas (Python)? There are two tabs in this worksheet. I'm referring to the second tab called "Table2".

For example, in the table below, I have several duplicates in the "Name" column. But for "Richard Madden" duplicates, corresponding values in "Amount" table (-4000) + (-6000) equals (-10000). I need to delete the entire rows for -4000 and -6000 and leave the row for -10000.

Here’s the Excel table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n2vZ.png

Here's my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

excel = pd.ExcelFile('/Users/user/Downloads/DSR-Table.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_excel(excel, 'Table2')

dfObj = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['Name'])
duplicateRowsDF = dfObj[dfObj.duplicated()]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the quickest way to do it in my opinion.

Some made up data based in your image:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
columns=["Name", "Amount"]
name=["Humming","Stanley","James","Humming","Igo","Madden","Madden","Samuels","McCallister","Samuels","Madden"]   
amount=[478028,333543,294376,199793,224,
-4000,-6000,-7886,-9331,-15043,-10000]
extra_name=["Smith","Smith","Smith"]
extra_amount=[3000,2000,-1000]
name+=extra_name
amount+=extra_amount

Table2=list(zip(name,amount))
df1=pd.DataFrame(Table2,columns=columns)
```

df1 is your real dataframe.

We define a aggregated function to retrieve   a list of indexes of duplicates rows for each name according your criteria:

```
def get_duplicates_idxs(self):
   idxs=[]
   if len(self)==3:
      amount=self.Amount
      indexes=amount.index
      idx1=indexes[0]
      idx2=indexes[1]
      idx3=indexes[2]
      a1=amount[idx1]
      a2=amount[idx2]
      a3=amount[idx3]
      if a1+a2==a3:
         idxs=[idx1,idx2]
      if a1+a3==a2:
         idxs=[idx1,idx3]
      if a2+a3==a1:
         idxs=[idx2,idx3]
   return idxs
```

There are two assumptions:

1. Duplicates implies 3 rows for that name.
2. The order of the 3 rows are irrelevant.

a1, a2 and a3 are the amounts of the posible duplicates rows in that order.

Then we apply this function in df1 grouped by name:

```
idxs_series=df1.groupby("Name").apply(lambda x: get_duplicates_idxs(x))
idxs_duplicates=(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(idxs_series)))

df_filtered=df1[~df1.index.isin(idxs_duplicates)]
```

df_filtered has the desired output.

Tools used:

[Pandas groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
[Pandas apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)
[itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)
[Python lambda functions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-lambda-anonymous-functions-filter-map-reduce/)

Comment: Thank you! I made some changes to it (see my answer posted here) and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer with help of the code above from Jorge N:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

excel = pd.ExcelFile('/Users/user/Downloads/DSR-Table.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_excel(excel, 'Table2') 
name = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['Name'])
amount = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['Amount'])
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(name, amount)), columns=['Name', 'Amount'])

def get_duplicates_idxs(self):
   idxs=[]
   if len(self)==3:
      amount=self.Amount
      indexes=amount.index
      idx1=indexes[0]
      idx2=indexes[1]
      idx3=indexes[2]
      a1=amount[idx1]
      a2=amount[idx2]
      a3=amount[idx3]
      if a1+a2==a3:
         idxs=[idx1,idx2]
      if a1+a3==a2:
         idxs=[idx1,idx3]
      if a2+a3==a1:
         idxs=[idx2,idx3]
   return idxs

idxs_series=df1.groupby("Name").apply(lambda x: get_duplicates_idxs(x))
idxs_duplicates=(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(idxs_series)))
df_filtered=df1[~df1.index.isin(idxs_duplicates)]
df_filtered.to_excel("/Users/user/Downloads/DSR-Table.xlsx", index = False)
```